# Software for generating Cayley graphs of $\mathbb Z_n$?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, soft-question, math-software, cayley-graphs

Does it exist any program (for linux) which can generate a nice Cayley graph of any $\mathbb Z_n$? (If it's possible to create such a graph at all, that is.)

(where perhaps $n ≤ 100$ or something like that)

Comment: You can generate Cayley graphs with the [GRAPE](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/grape.html) package of [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/).

Comment: The Cayley graph for $\mathbb{Z}_n$ with the standard generator is fairly boring, is it not?

Comment: @AlbertSteppi Thank you very much, I will try it out.

Comment: @ronno Well, I find the Cayley graphs of $\mathbb Z_6$ and $\mathbb Z_8$ kind of nice. Perhaps not mindblowing but neat.

Comment: Is $\mathbb Z_n$ the group of integers modulo $n$, or something else?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Yes I mean the good old lovely group of integers mod n. I should perhaps have specified this.

Comment: @JohnSmith: if you take the standard generator, then is the Cayley graph not just an $n$-gon?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Ah, yes of course. $<1>$ of $\mathbb Z_n$ isn't very awesome. I'm more interested in generating graphs using not only the standard generator but two or more. Like this http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/s31.png for $\mathbb Z_6$ using the generating set ${2,3}$.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Okay that makes more sense now.

Answer (score 7):

In [SageMath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SageMath): `g=graphs.CirculantGraph(8,[1,4,7])`

First argument is the number of vertices, second is the connection set. Now
`g.show()` produces a drawing.