# What programs can be used to construct a Cayley Graph?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cayley-graphs

What downloadable programs can I use to construct a Cayley Graph given a group with certain generators and relations?
Any guidance greatly appreciated!

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594079/software-for-generating-cayley-graphs-of-mathbb-z-n) answers the question specifically for $\mathbb Z_n$.  I believe the answer (using the GRAPE package in GAP) works for generic groups.  I'm unsure if the solution in SAGE works for generic groups though.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "construct a Cayley graph". Are you looking for a graphics program?

Comment: yes a graphic program